# Status of mysql.service: failed

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Wassup, brothers!

Mysql worked success. After I launched `mysql -u root -p`, entered with password and got a next message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

`systemctl status mysql.service` show next:

```
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-03 20:43:02 +05; 22mi>
    Process: 1492 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=e>
    Process: 1510 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1510 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
      Error: 22 (Invalid argument)
        CPU: 267ms

апр 03 20:43:02 p3c4 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart >
апр 03 20:43:02 p3c4 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
апр 03 20:43:02 p3c4 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quic>
апр 03 20:43:02 p3c4 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
апр 03 20:43:02 p3c4 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Do you know I can fix it?

I tried many methods for performance, but nothing help me. Even uninstalled and install mysql-server again. I stopped mysql.service and started again. There were more different errors. All broke!

UPD: /var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
023-04-05T05:38:26.418573Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1086
2023-04-05T05:38:26.533808Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556650Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556680Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 2 = ['forum/users.ibd', 'teaching/job_title.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556693Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['forum/topics.ibd', 'teaching/experience.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556706Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556724Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556822Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.556853Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-05T05:38:26.557253Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-04-05T05:38:26.958160Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1311
2023-04-05T05:38:26.963453Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971573Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971598Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 2 = ['forum/users.ibd', 'teaching/job_title.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971608Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['forum/topics.ibd', 'teaching/experience.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971616Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971631Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971721Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-05T05:38:26.971750Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-05T05:38:26.972147Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-04-05T05:38:27.350127Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1377
2023-04-05T05:38:27.355734Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367663Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367704Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 2 = ['forum/users.ibd', 'teaching/job_title.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367720Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['forum/topics.ibd', 'teaching/experience.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367734Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367765Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367877Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.367904Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-05T05:38:27.368322Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-04-05T05:38:27.741660Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1446
2023-04-05T05:38:27.747222Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754178Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754204Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 2 = ['forum/users.ibd', 'teaching/job_title.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754214Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['forum/topics.ibd', 'teaching/experience.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754224Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754240Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754332Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754357Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-05T05:38:27.754734Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-04-05T05:38:28.153974Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1540
2023-04-05T05:38:28.158680Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165181Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165203Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 2 = ['forum/users.ibd', 'teaching/job_title.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165213Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['forum/topics.ibd', 'teaching/experience.ibd'] 
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165221Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165234Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165358Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-04-05T05:38:28.165753Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant entries in the error log (default: /var/log/mysql/error.log) from the most recent start attempt.

Comment: @user1191247, error.log appended

Comment: Please share how your problem is related to programming. If it is not, please move your question to superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: It looks like the innoDB table files are corrupted. Try deleting the data files ( usually in /var/lib/mysql). Generate a backup before you do it.

Comment: Do you need to recover the contents of these tablespaces? If not, do an [uninstall/purge](https://www.fosslinux.com/96135), making sure to delete all files in the current data_dir, and then reinstall MySQL and reload your database[s] from a backup. If you need to recover the contents of these ibd files, you will need to follow the [DISCARD/IMPORT TABLESPACE process](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html#innodb-table-import-example), which will still require a clean install and the database structure to be rebuilt, to be able to import the existing tablespaces.

Comment: thank for all, I am deleted * from /var/lib/mysql and purged * packages. After installing mysql-server has worked again!